# using UIImage as a condition in an if statement

Tags: if-statement, uiimageview, nsdictionary

I am trying to load variables into a detail view controller from a NSDictionary in the primary view controller.

I am trying to use the images in the primary view Controller to determine which variable to use in the detail view controller.

My code is like this in the primary View controller;

```
-(IBAction)pushView:(id) sender{

    SomeDetailViewController *detailController = [[SomeDetailViewController alloc] init]; 


    if ((self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"0002.jpg"])) {
        NSMutableDictionary *myDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                              @"titleA", @"headerkey2",,nil];

        detailController.mapDictionary = mapDictionary;

        NSLog(@"%@", [myDictionary objectForKey:@"headerkey2"]);
    }

    else if((self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"0003.jpg"])) {
        NSMutableDictionary *myDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                              @"TitleB", @"headerkey2",,nil];

        detailController.myDictionary = myDictionary;

       NSLog(@"%@", [myDictionary objectForKey:@"headerkey2"]);
    }

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailController animated:YES];    

                                                }
```

then in my receiving detail view controller my code is;

```
-(void) viewDidLoad{
[super viewDidLoad];

self.title = [(NSMutableDictionary *)myDictionary objectForKey:@"headerkey2"];

}
```

Unfortunately this is not working.  The same thing shows up for the navigationBar title no matter what.

Can I use a UIImage as a condition?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have used the backlash but doesn't seem to be working in all cases.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use "=" in the if statement for some reason? if not, use "==" instead.

the doc says that [UIImage imageNamed] returns the object associated with specified image, which means it should always return the same object for a same image, so you can use UIImage in condition.

Comment: @user1114881 could you please check my answer as accepted if it works? I'll appreciate that.